# MinGW printf padding ignored with c89/c99/c11

Tags: c, gcc, printf, mingw

Trying to build+run this simple C program in MinGW produces strange results

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    printf("%03d", 7);
};
```

If I build it with any standard-C compliance flags (`-std=c89/99/11`) the padding is ignored:

```
C:\>gcc -std=c11 a.c
C:\>a
7
```

Whereas in regular GNU C mode it works fine:

```
C:\>gcc a.c
C:\>a
007
```

Is this a bug in MinGW? Have I missed something? Or is the padding specifier really not a standard C feature?

For reference, [here](http://pastie.org/10911705)'s the output of `gcc -v` on my system.

---

As suggested by [2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501), the best workaround is to instead use *MinGW-W64*, which is actually a separate project from MinGW. It can still produce 32-bit binaries, despite the "W64" label.

Comment: Why is your `main()` `void main()`??? That's wrong in all of the standards you're testing I think. You should enable compilation warnings specially if you are learning. I never turn them off except when I build a release where it would be pointless to make the compiler work more. But normally in debug builds, always `-Wall -Werror`. I like to keep the compiler as happy as possible to prevent having to check for *silly* mistakes by myself.

Comment: I deleted my answer since some people apparently beleive that It's wrong, although no one explained why. If it helped please let me know. But the downvoted answer is not "*useful*" so it's better deleted.

Comment: Thanks @iharob, but your points aren't really the issue here. `main` can safely have the wrong signature since it's a cdecl function (caller cleanup) and the arguments aren't used.

Comment: It was wrong indeed and the generated assembly is almost identical in both cases. I wonder how that relates, to the standard specification. It looks like it is indeed related to the bug you mention in the comment to the "now deleted" answer about the macro.

Comment: Apparently your compiler doesn't have the license to kill.

Comment: `-fno-builtin` is not the solution, in case anyone was going to suggest it. I tried that already.

Comment: Here's one workaround that seems to do the job:

`gcc -std=c11 -Wl,-u,_vprintf -Wl,--defsym,___mingw_vprintf=_vprintf a.c`.

Apparently `printf` gets rewritten to `__mingw_vprintf` by the compiler, so with these linker flags we're forcing the linker to substitute `__mingw_vprintf` with the MSVCRT `vprintf`, which behaves correctly.

Care should be taken though — I'm sure msvcrt.vprintf has its own set of pitfalls.

Comment: @Cauterite I suggest you install mingw-w64. It's like mingw but better, and doesn't have this flaw.

Comment: @2501 thanks, that's good to know

Comment: @iharob: see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for details of why it _might_ be OK to use `void` as the return type for `main()` on Windows platforms — though it isn't clear-cut when using the MinGW compiler whether the runtime library used supports it or not (it is 'OK' with the MS compiler and runtime library).